# CGI using MySQL: How to display all data from table?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, cgi

This is for a homework. When I run the script, it will only show one row of data from the database. `my @record = $sql->fetchAll();` is the problem, I think. How do I make it so it outputs ALL rows from the table?

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $idnum = param('idnum');
my $year = param('year');
my $make = param('make');
my $model = param('model');
my $color = param('color');
my $price = param('price');

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";;

my $db = "DBI:mysql:cars:localhost";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($db,"root","",{RaiseError=>1});

my $sql = $dbh->prepare(qq(select * from cars));
$sql->execute;

print <<here;

<div align="center">
<h2>Cars</h2>
<table border ="2" bordercolor="green">
<tr>
<td>Id</td><td>Year</td><td>Make</td><td>Model</td><td>Color</td>    <td>Price</td>
</TR>
here

my @record = $sql->fetchrow_array;  ### there is only one row in resultset

for(my $i = 0; $i < @record; $i++ ) {
    print "<td>$record[$i]</td>";
}
print "</tr>";

print "</table></div></body></html>";

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: How many records are there? Also, a DBI statement handle object doesn't have a `fetchAll` method according [to the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). Even if it had one, it would be `fetchall`, not `fetchAll`. None of the methods in DBI are camelcase. Only attributes are.

Comment: @simbabque 10 sir!

Comment: Are you sure this works at all? See the edit to my comment above.

Comment: @simbabque i'm sorry, this was the decoy testing script. I edited it. The one that works has `my @record = $sql->fetchrow_array; `

Comment: You need a loop to iterate over the results; see https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Simple-Examples

Comment: Also, I would recommend calling the statement handle `$sth` instead of `$sql`, since it's not SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchrow_array` method only returns one line at a time, until it's exhausted. It's an *iterator*. So your code correctly prints one row at a time.

You need to iterate the results until there are no more left.

```
while (my @record = $sql->fetchrow_array) {
   print "<tr>";
   print "<td>$_</td>" foreach @record;
   print "</tr>";
}
```

I've used the considerably shorter `foreach @record`, which gives you each  element in the array, one by one. That way you don't need to deal with indexes. Putting it after the line you want to repeat in the loop is called *postfix notation*.

Comment: @J no problem. But next time please at least read part of the documentation. It was all right there. Matt's comment above has the relevant link.